# Python create a sequence of non repeating numbers

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

I want to create a sequence something like this `[[1,2],[3,4],[5,6],..]`.
Here is what I tried and got:

```
n = 3 # I need three lists
for i in range(0,n+1,1):  
    print(i+1,i+2)
1 2
2 3
3 4
4 5
```

Expected output:

```
1 2
3 4
5 6
```

Comment: You mention lists, but the expected result doesn't seem like a list. What are you looking for exactly?

Comment: use `for i in range(0,n*2,2): `

Comment: `np.arange(6).reshape((3, 2))`

Comment: `for i in range(0,n*2,2):` produces correct result for different n.

Answer (score 0):

```
n = 3

pairs = [list([i, i + 1]) for i in range (1, 2 * n, 2)]
for pair in pairs:
    for x in pair:
        print(x, end = ' ')

    print()
```

This prints:

```
1 2 
3 4 
5 6
```

And the list `pairs` so formed is:

```
[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Take step of 2 and end at n*2

```
n=3
output = []
for i in range(0,n*2,2):
    print(i+1,i+2)
    output.append([i+1,i+2])
print(output)


1 2
3 4
5 6
[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]
```

Answer (score 0):

After a trial, I found the following answer:

```
for i in range(0,n,1):
    print(2*i+1,2*i+2)
```